# The `functools.cmp_to_key` isn't working on this comparison of two-tuple problem

Tags: python, functools

For `cmp_to_key(fn)`, I read in the documentation that `fn(a,b)` should return `-1` if `a` should come before `b` and `0` is equal, and `1` if `a` should come after `b` in the ordering.

I have this input

```
smith 20
jones 15
jones 20
```

which I store as tuple, so my comparator is and I want to score sort by score (2nd column) in *descending* order and sort by name (1st column) in *ascedending* order.

```
def comparator(a, b):
  if a[1] > b[1]:
    return -1
  if a[0] < b[0]:
    return -1
  if (a[0] == b[0]) and (a[1] == b[1]):
    return 0
  return 1
```

and I go

```
sorted(data, key=cmp_to_key(comparator))
```

But What I get is this

```
jones 20
jones 15
smith 20
```

which is not correct. Where am I not understanding the `cmp_to_key` function?

Comment: The point of Python switching to key functions was that directly writing a key function is *clearer* and less error-prone than using a comparator. `cmp_to_key` exists almost entirely as a Python 2 to 3 transition aid, not as something you should use in new code.

Comment: Your key could just be `lambda x: (-x[1], x[0])`.

Answer (score 3):

Your issue is that the comparator function doesn't give the correct result when `b[1]` is less than `a[1]`; it should return 1 regardless of the values of `a[0]` and `b[0]`. You can rewrite it more simply as:

```
def comparator(a, b):
  if a[1] != b[1]:
    return b[1] - a[1]
  if a[0] != b[0]:
    return -1 if a[0] < b[0] else 1
  return 0

data = [['smith', 20],
        ['jones', 15],
        ['jones', 20]
       ]

print(sorted(data, key=cmp_to_key(comparator)))
```

Output from sorting

```
[
 ['jones', 20],
 ['smith', 20],
 ['jones', 15]
]
```

It should be noted that you could just use a lambda function, negating the `score` value so that it sorts descending:

```
print(sorted(data, key=lambda x:(-x[1], x[0])))
```